# Javascript 'select' on change go to anchor (anchor id is the select value)

Tags: javascript

I have my script creating a dropdown box (select) and populating the values with items from an array that I looped through. The values of these items are also the same as the id's for anchor points throughout the page. I'm trying to make it so when the select is changed, it goes to the anchor point that matches the value of the select.

`error_anchor` is an array of items where the values are also the same as the anchor id's

```
for (var i = 0; i < error_anchor.length; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");

  option.setAttribute("value", error_anchor[i]);
  option.text = error_anchor[I];
  option.onChange="window.location.hash=this.value";

  selectList.appendChild(option);
};
```

This doesn't throw an error but it doesn't do anything when I change the select value. I read online about using `this.value` and figured it would use the selected value, but perhaps it was just a placeholder in someone else's example?

I tried placing the `onChange` line outside of the loop, as I suppose it doesn't need to be in there, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Would appreciate the help! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event name is `onchange` not `onChange` and you should assign a function to it (not a string).

Also, the event should be on the select, not the options. `this.value` will contain the current chosen option value.

You can see a [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/qkh3o8av/)

Comment: Ah that makes sense now. Thanks for your help!